# There is no richtextbox control in my Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App

Tags: xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I need to add a RichTextBox or RichTextBlock to my Windows Phone App. I started developing my app in Windows Phone Sileverlight 8.1. I could add "`<RichTextBox> </RichTextBox>`" in xaml page, and it shows the RichTextBox control in the designer. But when I install the application in my Windows Phone, the RichTextBox control is not working, means we cannot insert any text in the box.

Please help me to resolve this problem. Is there any alternative toolkit for getting RichTextBox/RichTextBlock in my app.

Comment: What exactly you are using to insert text in RichTextBox, can you provide some code ?

Comment: <RichTextBox IsEnabled="True"  Margin="6,0,6,0"> </RichTextBox>     This  is my code in xaml page which adds Rich Textbox to my app.

Comment: I mean why you can't insert text in "RichTextBox", what did you do to insert text and not working ?

Comment: That is because the RichTextBox is acting as READ ONLY when the application runs. I have found out from MSDN that "In Silverlight for Windows Phone, RichTextBox is read-only". Do you have any idea to get an editable RichTextBox in my Windows Phone Silverlight application?